# Windows IIS SMTP service: where to find/change the outgoing mails' sender address

Tags: iis, smtp

We have a website, and it uses Windows IIS SMTP service to send out emails (only send out emails).

I am asked to change the sender's email address, but I am not able to find it on the server.